# JDBC data sources managed by server?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jdbc

What are exactly the benefits of JDBC data sources managed by an application server, instead of being created by the application itself?

Comment: Did you do any research? Google for e.g. 'connection pooling` and please read the FAQ before asking questions.

Comment: I think it is a perfectly legitimate question and it is hard to research this kind of thing yourself if you dont have a lot of experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are a few of them...

- Connection pooling
- Distributed transactions
- Abstraction of data source location (You usually access through JNDI and you configure it in your app server)
- Monitoring (The app server is likely to give you for free monitoring utilities for your configured data sources)